# Google Sign In Javascript API issue

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I am using below to render google login button in an Angular project.

```
google.accounts.id.renderButton(element, {
        shape: 'rectangle',
        size: 'small',
        type: 'standard',
        width: '250',
      });
```

It was working until recently. It was getting error that width needs to be a string.

`width: 250` solve the issue.

But checked the [google docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#width). It still says width needs to be a string.
Any idea if it is a documentation error from google?

Comment: I think it’s a bug all around

Comment: The link https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#width clearly says and provides an example (`width: 400`) with a integer width, so I don't see a discrepancy there.

Comment: put px after 250. just like this, width:'250px'
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76796549/google-login-ui-crashing?noredirect=1#comment135398238_76796549

Comment: @AreebHashir thank you but if you put px you don't get expected width and also nowhere in documentation says it needs to have px

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there might be a recent change or inconsistency in the Google Sign-In JavaScript API behavior regarding the width property. According to the Google documentation, the width property should be a string, but in your case, using a number (width: 250) is resolving the issue.

To ensure accurate behavior, you can try explicitly passing the width as a string to see if it works as expected:

```
google.accounts.id.renderButton(element, {
  shape: 'rectangle',
  size: 'small',
  type: 'standard',
  width: '250', // Ensure width is passed as a string
});
```

If passing the width as a string ('250') works without any issues, it's possible that there might be a documentation error in the Google documentation, and the width property should indeed accept a number instead of a string.

However, to be cautious, it's best to stick to the documented behavior for production purposes. If the official documentation states that the width property should be a string, it's advisable to follow that guideline. In such cases, you can consider keeping the width property as a string to avoid any potential conflicts or issues in the future.

If you encounter any specific errors or issues with either approach, you can try reaching out to Google Sign-In support or their community forums to get clarification on the recent changes or potential documentation discrepancies. They would be in the best position to provide accurate information and solutions for any Google Sign-In API issues.