# renderButton stops working and not showing google sign in button Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, google-signin

This was working fine until now.

**ERROR in console - indicating the issue with the line with "renderButton"**

[image]

login.component.ts

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: 'XXXXX',
            callback: this.handleCredentialResponse.bind(this),
            auto_select: false,
            cancel_on_tap_outside: true,

        });
        
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(
            document.getElementById('google-button'),
            { theme: 'filled_blue', size: 'large', width: '215' }
        );
 }
```

login.component.html

```html
<div id="google-button"></div>.
```

I tried:

1. Moving the code from `ngAfterViewInit` to `ngOnInit` - it was just a try.
2. Wrapping the code inside `ngAfterViewInit` to `setTimeout(()=> { // here })` doesn't work.

Comment: You may find the comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76803838/google-sign-in-javascript-api-issue) helpful.  There's also an answer that appears to be generated with ChatGPT. :-o

Comment: Thank you @BizzyBob for the reference! Turns out to be the same issue. From the error, it wasn't clear it could be the width!

Answer (score 0):

It was the width attribute passed in the second parameter that now required to be a number value only.

```json
{ theme: 'filled_blue', size: 'large', width: 215 }
```

That solved the issue. It wasn't clear from the error initially.

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#width